# Recursive Loop in table React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, loops, recursion

Is it possible to render dynamic columns and also data on column bases

I'm trying to render dynamic table columns and also its data on the basis of array in react JS.

```
var cols = ["Id", "Name"];
const generateData = () => {
    var testArr = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        testArr.push({ Id: i + 1, Name: names[Math.round(Math.random() * 10)] });
    }
    return testArr;
}

import { Table } from "reactstrap";

function dynamicTables(props) {
    debugger
    return (
        <Table className="align-items-center table-flush" responsive>
            <thead className="thead-light">
                <tr>
                    {
                        props.cols.map((item, key) => (
                            <th key={key}>{item}</th>
                        ))
                    }
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                {
                    props.data.map((item, key) => (
                        <tr key={key}>
                            {
                                props.cols.map((col) => {
                                    <td>{item[col]}</td>
                                })
                            }
                        </tr>
                    ))
                }
            </tbody>
        </Table>
    );
}

export default dynamicTables;
```

Calling Component:

```
<dynamicTables data={generateData()} cols={cols}></dynamicTables>
```

Comment: Have you tried?

Comment: Yes, I have try

Comment: And is it possible?

Comment: Yes it is possible and I resolved it. Thanks @Konrad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me

```
var cols = ["Id", "Name"];
const generateData = () => {
    var testArr = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        testArr.push({ Id: i + 1, Name: names[Math.round(Math.random() * 10)] });
    }
    return testArr;
}

import { Table } from "reactstrap";

function dynamicTables(props) {
    debugger
    return (
        <Table className="align-items-center table-flush" responsive>
            <thead className="thead-light">
                <tr>
                    {
                        props.cols.map((item, key) => (
                            <th key={key}>{item}</th>
                        ))
                    }
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                {
                    props.data.map((item, key) => (
                        <tr key={key}>
                            {
                                props.cols.map((col) => {
                                    return <td>{item[col]}</td>
                                })
                            }
                        </tr>
                    ))
                }
            </tbody>
        </Table>
    );
}

export default dynamicTables;
```